# How can I get puppeteer objects from within a test?

Tags: node.js, sapui5, puppeteer, karma-runner

I am writing tests using SAPUI5, Opa5, and karma. I'm trying to add the ability to take screenshots from a test, so I looked into puppeteer. I added this to my `karma.conf.js` file:

```
process.env.CHROME_BIN = require( 'puppeteer' ).executablePath();
config.customLaunchers = {
    'ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox': {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: [ '--no-sandbox' ]
    }
};
config.browsers = [ 'ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox' ];
```

The tests now run through headless Chrome. I'd like to use the `page.screenshot` function in one of my tests, but to do that I need a page object. The docs tell you to get the browser object from `puppeteer.launch` (and then create the page from there) but I'm not calling that directly, karma is doing that for me. The test has already created and rendered the page, so I don't need to *create* anything, I just want a Page object that refers to the current page. How can I get that?